# Apache tomcat server static files based on header

Tags: java, macos, apache, tomcat, static

I am facing issue with tomcat server. Here is the scenario.
    I have client running in port 8999 and using apache tomcat to serve static contents.
    [http://hostname1:8999/client/static](http://google.com)

```
And server running in another port 9001 and using another tomcat. 
[http://hostname1:9001/server/][2]

i have configured re-routing rules in httpd.conf file to make them work together. 

Now, my issue is, the static content is served without any authentication.
I want to stop that and make sure, the static contents will be served only when request is from server or when it contains any kind of headers.

How can i achieve this?

I tried adding security contraints in web.xml of tomcat.

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>HTTP-Protected-Resource-1</web-resource-name>
<description>Description here</description>
<url-pattern>/scripts/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/styles/*</url-pattern>
<http-method>GET</http-method>
<http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>NOSOUPFORYOU</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
<auth-method>DEFAULT</auth-method>
<realm-name>NOACCESSFORANYONE</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
<role-name>NOSOUPFORYOU</role-name>
</security-role>

It worked, but it is blocking content in all cases even when the call is from server.
Can i distinguish request  or check for headers in web.xml?
```

Comment: It is not clear who is performing static request. Browser -> Apache (URL Rewrite?) -> hostname1:8999 for static content and hostname1:9001 for dynamic content?

Comment: Apache tomcat is serving static content.

Comment: Basically, i want to override default behaviour of apache tomcat to serve static content based on headers.

Comment: How can i override default servlet of apache tomcat to serve static content.

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to understand. You want to protect resources served but the static tomcat? But this will lead to a double login in your application. It's impossible for your static tomcat to know that a user has been logged to the dynamic tomcat.

Comment: Working with headers you could implement a ServletFilter (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). The filter will answer HTTP403 if some custom headers are not set or authorize the request in the other case. I still don't understand which component will set those headers.